# Cannot access port inside of docker from the host when running the docker container in host networking mode

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-container

### Problem

I previously compiled a docker that is implemented in flask:

```
docker build -t stamaki:latest .
```

And I attempted to run it:

```
docker run -d --network="host" stamaki
```

Note that I have to run it on network host mode in order to let the inside of the docker to get access to the port of some of the other applications running outside of the docker.

The running appears to be successful:

```
 * Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:28500/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

However, on my host machine, I can not get access to this port:

```
stamaki@~$ curl -X GET localhost:28500/ping
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 28500: Connection refused
```

weirdly from inside the host it does work:

```
root@linuxkit-025000000001:/opt/stamaki# curl -X GET localhost:28500/ping
{"value":"pong"}
```

### Some Failed Attempts

```
docker run -d --expose 28500 --network="host" stamaki
```

It does not work either

```
docker run -d -p 28500:28500 --network="host" stamaki
```

Well, docker manual explicitly said this won't work, I just tried again and it does not work indeed

```
docker run -d -p 28500:28500 stamaki
```

This opens me port 28500 on the host but I can not access some other server that runs outside of dockers from within this container so it doesn't solve the problem for me.

```
curl -X GET 127.0.0.1:28500/ping
curl -X GET 0.0.0.0:28500/ping
```

Nope, adding `http://` also present zero effect.

Comment: Are you on a MacOS host (hence that `linuxkit` prompt)?  [Host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) doesn't work there; it shouldn't be necessary for simple HTTP applications in any case.

Comment: wow thank you! Didn't read that part carefully enough. Yeah I suppose I will have to test it on a server, just wanted to confirm it's working reasonably on my local machine before I started burning money for AWS. @DavidMaze

Comment: The normal `docker run -p` option to publish a port out of a container works fine (on both Docker Desktop and native Linux environments).

Comment: So what was the solution?

Comment: @GerardoFigueroa I decided to run that on a Linux host. If you may insist run on Mac, you can use docker-compose. It is much more complicated to be done correctly than docker run indeed but it offers better networking functionality under Mac.